# The document has not been opened Using crystal report

Tags: c#, windows, crystal-reports, desktop-application

I have created one software. but in my developer machine crystal report generated successfully but when i am install software in client machine it's give this error. i have checked many solution in stack overflow but i cant find any solutions. If any have solution for this then that will help me.

> CrystalDecisions.Shared.CrystalReportsException: Load report failed.
>   ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The document has not been opened.    at
>   CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc.ReportClientDocumentClass.get_ReportAppServer()
>   at
>   CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.get_ReportAppServer()
>   at
>   CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.EnsureDocumentIsOpened()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Symbols.Container.InvokeMethod(Method
>   TargetProcedure, Object[] Arguments, Boolean[] CopyBack, BindingFlags
>   Flags)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.ObjectLateGet(Object
>   Instance, Type Type, String MemberName, Object[] Arguments, String[]
>   ArgumentNames, Type[] TypeArguments, Boolean[] CopyBack)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.LateGet(Object
>   Instance, Type Type, String MemberName, Object[] Arguments, String[]
>   ArgumentNames, Type[] TypeArguments, Boolean[] CopyBack)    at
>   Inventory.frmCstReport.btnShow_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons
>   button, Int32 clicks)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg,
>   IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Crystal Reports runtime installed on the server probably doesn't match the version you are developing with.